# read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count): prevent implicit conversion

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, pipe

On Linux (amd64) i read from a pipe some data of a related process. I want to ensure, that the read bytes are not changed and prevent implicit type and value conversion.

Could there happen any type conversions with "trap values" when i put the data in char or unsigned char Arrays (see the #ifdef) or should i better use a vector<> for the data read from the child? What could happen when i use a diferent platform like arm (raspi/beaglebone)? Could a conversion happen at the std::back_inserter?

```
        #ifdef USE_UCHAR
        using buffer_type = unsigned char;
        #else
        using buffer_type = char;
        #endif

        std::string from_child;

        std::array<buffer_type, PIPE_BUF> buffer;
        ....
        // read from it
        long bytes_read = read(fd, buffer.data(), buffer.size());
        if (bytes_read > 0) {
            std::copy_n(buffer.data(), bytes_read, std::back_inserter(from_child) );
        }
        else if (bytes_read == 0)  {
            // eof
            run = false;
        }
        else {
            perror("read from pipe:");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` and `unsigned char` are required to treat every bit as a value bit.  In addition, they are required to roundtrip, which prohibits conversions and trap values.

And `std::string`, for all its string-manipulation convenience functions, is at its core just a collection of characters.  Inserting and iterating characters will never fail, only the string manipulation convenience functions actually assume that the character data represents a valid string.

If there were any problem, `std::vector` wouldn't help you, since it uses a dynamic array for holding its contents anyway.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean by "valid string" and how do the string manipulation convenience functions assume one?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Things like `operator<<(ostream&, const std::string&)` might go wonky if you have a stream imbued with a UTF-8 locale and the string content isn't valid UTF-8.  Other functions might fail if you have embedded `'\0'`.  Even more common than "failures" will be functions that behave in unwanted and totally useless (but Standard-conforming) ways.

Comment: I'm not aware that any `std::string` functions care about `'\0'` nor about UTF-8. If you have a stream imbued with a UTF-8 locale and the string content isn't valid UTF-8 then that's the stream's problem. Strings contain bytes, nothing more! You say that yourself... AFAIK all `std::basic_string`'s functions are okay with that.